# Manipulating all elements of the Series object

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and learning. Coming from a .net background.
Currently I'm learning pandas series and having trouble understanding *how this statement produced the intended result*.

lc['int_rate'] is of type pandas.core.series.Series obtained from a DataFrame. It contains values in the format of 12.34%.
The following statement strips the percent symbol out and converts the individual values to a float64 object.

```
lc['int_rate'].str.replace("%","").astype('float')
```

I am trying to understand how this one statement manipulated all the elements of the series at one shot. Playing around, i tried the following and as expected it gave me a single concatenated string from the series.

```
str = ""
for i in lc['int_rate']:
    if type(i) == type(str):
        str = str + " " + i
print(str)
```

But from this statement onwards, I'm confused. I get the warning, *FutureWarning: Columnar iteration over characters will be deprecated in future releases*. It seems to be iterating over characters of the string. And gives me no output.

```
str = ""
for i in lc['int_rate'].str:
    if type(i) == type(str):
        str = str + " " + i

print(str)
```

iter(lc['int_rate']) produces a map object.

iter(lc['int_rate'].str) produces a generator object.

Also .str being a property, How did the property result with a generator object?

Comment: You have too many questions. Try narrowing one post to focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: Check out the pandas documentation on [Vectorized string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods). Essentially, `.str` is an attribute that exposes some vectorized string methods that operate on each element in the array (such as `.replace` in your example). A lot of pandas and numpy's speed come from these vectorized operations.

Comment: I think that you should read the [introduction to Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html#getting-started)

Comment: Will go through the links, thanks!